# How can i resort this json to sort on price?

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is my current json array is it possible to resort the array on the price decending? I have not been able to figure out what i need to do to get the proper output

```
Array
(
    [5952418516] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5952418516
            [name] => AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)
            [image] => https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5lpKKqPrxN7LEmyVQ7MEpiLuSrYmnjQO3-UdsZGHyd4_Bd1RvNQ7T_FDrw-_ng5Pu75iY1zI97bhLsvQz
            [type] => weapon
            [price] => 4.73
        )

    [5912178664] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5912178664
            [name] => AWP | Worm God (Field-Tested)
            [image] => https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FAZx7PLfYQJW-9W4kb-GkvP9JrafxG0GscMhjLqW9t7zjVfn8hc6MmmnI9CTclRrYgrU_Vfowefs18K6uIOJlyXpUGetdA
            [type] => weapon
            [price] => 0.78
        )
[5746271006] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5746271006
        [name] => AWP | Hyper Beast (Factory New)
        [image] => https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FAR17PLfYQJK9cyzhr-JkvbnJ4Tdn2xZ_Ismju2To9qm31Hsr0ZsMTryJo_BcANrMwyCrFLrx7vrhJa1vZrByXo2pGB8sr2_Epwm
        [type] => weapon
        [price] => 54.2
    )

)
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Language are you dealing with here? PHP or Javascript?
Most of the Solutions provided are PHP-Based. If you have control over the Source-Code and would like to Sort the Data before shipping it as a JSON; PHP is the way to go like @RomanPerekhrest and @hdˑ already suggested -  though I'd add here again only for emphasis like so:

```
    <?php
        $gamePayload = "COLLECTION_OR_ARRAY_OF_DATA_FROM_DATASOURCE_LIKE_DB_OR_SO";
        uasort($gamePayload, function($gp1, $gp2){
            return $gp2['price'] - $gp1['price']; 
        });
        // SORTS THE THE DATA IN DESCENDING ORDER.
        // IF YOU WANT IT SORTED IN ASCENDING ORDER;
        // CHANGE::  return $gp2['price'] - $gp1['price'] 
        // TO::      return $gp1['price'] - $gp2['price']
```

On the other hand, if the JSON Data is coming from another Source (which means you cannot do much to change the Ordering from the Data-Source), Javascript is the way to go like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jsonData    = [
    {
        id:     5952418516,
        name:   'AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)',
        image:  'https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5lpKKqPrxN7LEmyVQ7MEpiLuSrYmnjQO3-UdsZGHyd4_Bd1RvNQ7T_FDrw-_ng5Pu75iY1zI97bhLsvQz',
        type:   'weapon',
        price:  4.73
    },

    {
        id:     5912178664,
        name:   'AWP | Worm God (Field-Tested)',
        image:  'https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FAZx7PLfYQJW-9W4kb-GkvP9JrafxG0GscMhjLqW9t7zjVfn8hc6MmmnI9CTclRrYgrU_Vfowefs18K6uIOJlyXpUGetdA',
        type:   'weapon',
        price:  0.78
    },

    {
        id:     5746271006,
        name:   'AWP | Hyper Beast (Factory New)',
        image:  'https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FAR17PLfYQJK9cyzhr-JkvbnJ4Tdn2xZ_Ismju2To9qm31Hsr0ZsMTryJo_BcANrMwyCrFLrx7vrhJa1vZrByXo2pGB8sr2_Epwm',
        type:   'weapon',
        price:  54.2
    }

];

var mm = jsonData.sort(function(jsonObj1, jsonObj2) {
    return parseFloat(jsonObj1.price) - parseFloat(jsonObj2.price);
});
// DISPLAYS THE DATA IN DESCENDING ORDER.
// IF YOU WANT IT SORTED IN ASCENDING ORDER;
// CHANGE::  return parseFloat(jsonObj1.price) - parseFloat(jsonObj2.price) 
// TO::      return parseFloat(jsonObj2.price) - parseFloat(jsonObj1.price)
console.log(mm);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort), you can compare values and sort the arrays based on the comparison.

```
uasort($array, function($a,$b) {
   return $a['price'] < $b['price'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

https://eval.in/564645

Answer (score 0):

Use `uasort` function for such purpose:

```
// $arr is your initial array
uasort($arr, function($a, $b){
    return $b['price'] - $a['price']; // sorting by descending price
});
```

Comment: Ive tried this and xDebug returns me an false statement on the usort

Comment: What i need to do is resort the array and then send the array back to the view now its just returning either true or false is there a way to resend the new array back after sorting?

Comment: `usort` , `uasort` functions don't return sorted array, they sort an array in place. Pay attention http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php. I've change it to `uasort` in case it should preserve keys